# build a control file to reformat source file with <wbr>

Tags: regex, sed, awk

My problem: long chemical terms, without any guidance to a browser about where to break the term. Some terms are over 70 characters.

My goal: introduce `<wbr>` at logical insertion points.

Example of problem:

- isoquinolinetetramethylenesulfoxidetetrachlororuthenate (55 chars)

Example of opportunities to break a chemical term (e.g. the way a person would pronounce the term as opposed to typing the term):

- iso`<wbr>`quinoline
- tetra`<wbr>`methylene
- methylene`<wbr>`sulfoxide
- tetra`<wbr>`chloro

Usually (but not always) iso, tetra, and methyl are word_break_opportunities.

In general how should I set up an environment with:

- control file with "rules" that introduce word_break opportunities
- file on which to apply the rules from the control file

The control file will be updated with new rules as new chemical term are encountered.

Would like to use: sed, awk, regex.

Perhaps the environment would look like:

```
awk rules.awk inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Am prepared for trial and error so would appreciate basic explanation so I can refine the control file.

My platform: Windows 7; 64 bit; 8 GB memory; GNUwin32; sed 4.1.5.4013; awk 3.1.6.2962

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60219/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-insert-line-breaks-into-a-long-string

Comment: What is your preferred line width? If you set a preferred width, the linebreak should occurs approximately around that column?

Comment: very difficult to decide/predict/determine. Hoping for a solution that is more logical (i.e. the break makes sense when read in a browser) v. physical (i.e. line length). Ultimately, looking for a 3-line maximum (e.g. the browser will format the chemical term in a space that will accommodate 3 lines).

Comment: Sorry, I think misunderstood the `<wbr>` tag.. i thought it was `<br>` you meant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first job is to come up with a list of what is and isn't breakable. Once you have this you can define a format to interpret, and build some code around it.

For example, I would probably go something like:

1. Opening chars:
   iso
   tetra

then some code like:

```
for Each openingString {
  if (string.startsWith(openingString)){
    insert wbr after opening string
  }
}
```

2.
Opening chars, unless followed by
iso|"tope|bob"
tetra|"pak"

```
for Each openingString {
  if (string.startsWith(openingString)){
    get the next element from the row (after the |, surrounded by ")        
    split around the | 
    for each part
      if (!string.startsWith(part, openingString.length)) {
        insert wbr after openingString
      }
  }
}
```

then build up from there. It's a pretty monumental task though, it's going to take a lot of building on to get to something useful, but if you're committed to it! The first task is to decide how you're going to hold these mappings though.

Comment: I'll start small (e.g. with terms that have iso and tetra, and then build from there). Thank you for a good answer that I can build on.